# How to deal with straggler reducers in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have a very simple use case... 
Basically I have an edge list and I am trying to convert it into adjacency list..
Basically

```
src target
a     b
a    c
b    d
b    e
```

and so on..
What I am trying to build is

```
a [b,c]
b [d,e]
.. and so on..
```

But every now and then.. I hit a super node..which has millions of edges..

Thus keying on just node id is results in poor MR execution because of this straggler reducer..

I have been trying to understand partitioner.. but I am at lost how to use it here?

How do i solve this straggler issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what's your purpose. You what to generate a single output file? Or you want to  speed up?

If you want to get single output file, then you could set the number of reducers  to 1.

Or you could use the srcID as key and targetID as value to the map, so that the k-v pairs which has the same srcID can be combined in the same reducer.